# How to load > 1 million items to a SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone suggest a reasonably practical and efficient way to load 1.2 million test items into a SharePoint Online list?

Background: We've decided to build a new application on top of SharePoint Online. Other application architecture options have all proved non-viable for various reasons. The application will use several SharePoint lists for persistence, one of which will be large, about 1.2 million items at peak. (Yes, we're planning ways to handle the 5000 item view limit.) To test viability of the architecture (including those view limit tactics) we need to create 1.2M test items in a list. Nothing we've tried has been practical:

- Tried making POST calls to the REST API, with 5 concurrent threads so it will finish in a reasonable time. This fails after a bit with a HTTP 429 "Too many requests".
- Tried uploading a spreadsheet with 1.2M rows. This fails at 130K entries each time, and I don't see a practical way to either upload / append to an existing list, nor to append items from one list to another existing list.
- Tried running a Workflow (SharePoint 2013 variety, if that matters). This works but runs way too slow single threaded and I'm hesitant to try multiple concurrent workflows because this is a shared environment and if I trash the server that would be way not good.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pnp powershell to add more than 1 million items.

```
$username = "amos@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credentials $cred
$ListName ="testn"
 for($i=0;$i -lt 1000001;$i++){
Add-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Values @{"Title" = "test";}    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Amos_MSFT. I'd love to be able to use PnP but I don't think it's available in our very locked down environment; I'll check. Even if we can get PnP, it may not work because we use PIV / CAC cards for authentication, not username / password.

Comment: Update: Somewhat to my surprise I was able to use this approach in our environment. Once I got it installed and got the right authentication for our environment, it looks like it works. (BTW, here we use this to authenticate: Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://(our server url) -UseWeblogin) I haven't tried creating a very large number of records yet, but when I do I'll plan to report back here how it goes. Thanks again @Amos_MSFT!

Comment: This worked and was by far the most practical approach we tried. However, we only got about 10% of the records we wanted. Looks like SharePoint online is only capable of loading around 10K records / hour.

Comment: The amount of data is too big.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to load and process items from SPO using PnPPowershell goes something like following. Idea is to not initialize the items collection in any variable and directly process the items by page size.

Get-PnpListItem -List "{ListName}" -Fields "Field1","Field2","Fieldn" -PageSize 5000 | % {$i=0}{

## % {$i=0}{

Do not move **{** to next line, I know it's weird but if you move, then good luck.

$item = $_

#Do your stuff with $item

Write-Host $item.Id

}

Answer (score 0):

This Power Automate template uses the batch API to update & create many records at once.

I haven’t tried maxing out the concurrency for the section with the batch calls yet, but if the SharePoint back-end can sustain 50 batch calls per minute, then it might be able to load up to 10,000 items per minute.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Batch-Update-Create-and-Upsert-SharePoint-Lists/td-p/1365410